# Python Pandas Concat "WHERE" a Condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, join, where-clause, concatenation

How can I "concat" a specific column from many Python Pandas dataframes, WHERE another column in each of the many dataframes meets a certain condition (colloquially termed condition "X" here).

In SQL this would be simple using JOIN clause with WHERE df2.Col2 = "X" and df3.Col2 = "X" and df4.col2 = "X"... etc (which can be run dynamically).

In my case, I want to create a big dataframe with all the "Col1"s from each of the many dataframes, but only include the Col1 row values WHERE the corresponding Col2 row value is greater than "0.8". When this condition isn't met, the Col1 value should be "NaN".

Any ideas would be most helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide data. Concatenate means stacking dataframes and so the analogous SQL statement would be `UNION`. Merge would correspond to `JOIN`. Also `WHERE` means filtering rows but you are describing conditional changing values and so keep rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider the `list` `dfs` of `pd.DataFrame`s

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed([3,1415])
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2),
                    columns=['Col1', 'Col2']) for _ in range(5)]
```

I'll use `pd.concat` to join

***raw concat***
stack values without regard to where it came from

```
pd.concat([d.Col1.loc[d.Col2.gt(.8)] for d in dfs], ignore_index=True)

0     0.850445
1     0.934829
2     0.879891
3     0.085823
4     0.739635
5     0.700566
6     0.542329
7     0.882029
8     0.496250
9     0.585309
10    0.883372
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

***join with source information***
use the `keys` parameter

```
pd.concat([d.Col1.loc[d.Col2.gt(.8)] for d in dfs], keys=range(len(dfs)))

0  3    0.850445
   5    0.934829
   6    0.879891
1  1    0.085823
   2    0.739635
   7    0.700566
2  4    0.542329
3  3    0.882029
   4    0.496250
   8    0.585309
4  0    0.883372
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

***another approach***
use `query`

```
pd.concat([d.query('Col2 > .8').Col1 for d in dfs], keys=range(len(dfs)))

0  3    0.850445
   5    0.934829
   6    0.879891
1  1    0.085823
   2    0.739635
   7    0.700566
2  4    0.542329
3  3    0.882029
   4    0.496250
   8    0.585309
4  0    0.883372
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks again @piRSquared!