# Pandas Concatenate/Merge Two Dataframes with Priority

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

How can you concatenate | merge two pandas dataframes with priority, keeping the row from a priority dataframe if a specific column value matches. Is there a type of join that describes this?

```
import pandas as pd
Cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]}
Cars2 = {'Brand': ['Honda CRV','Toyota Celica','Ford Explorer','Audi A8'],
        'Price': [40000,25000,37000,100000]}

df_priority = pd.DataFrame(Cars, columns= ['Brand', 'Price'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Cars2, columns= ['Brand', 'Price'])

# df_merge_with_priority = Merge dataframes and keep rows from df_priority if price matches
```

df_merge_with_priority expected output:

Brand: Honda CRV, Honda Civic, **Toyota Corolla**, Ford Explorer, Ford Focus, Audi A4, Audi A8

Price: 40000, 22000, **25000**, 27000, 37000, 35000, 100000

Notice how the price of the Toyota Corolla and Toyota Celica are the same however, we want to keep only the Corolla in this instance. Any thoughts on how to join with priority?

Comment: You can use pandas concat function with a query for condition  see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065641/python-pandas-concat-where-a-condition-is-met hope this help see the query part

Comment: try this `pd.concat([df_priority, df2]).groupby(['Price']).aggregate('max')` if this is your requirement or not?

Comment: are you looking for `pd.concat((df_priority,df2)).sort_index().drop_duplicates('Price')` ?

Comment: Hey @vb_rises, this works great! thank you

Comment: Thank you @Prof.Mo, however I am unsure how to interpret the question you provided, it seems to me that it is a conditional concatenate rather than concatenating with a priority

Comment: Hey @anky_91, This works well too, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are looking for the first of priority vs df2, you can try with:

```
pd.concat((df_priority,df2)).sort_index().drop_duplicates('Price') #.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
            Brand   Price
0     Honda Civic   22000
1       Honda CRV   40000
2  Toyota Corolla   25000
3      Ford Focus   27000
4   Ford Explorer   37000
5         Audi A4   35000
6         Audi A8  100000
```